# How to use BizTalk Health Monitor with an authenticating proxy?

Tags: biztalk, bhm

How to use BizTalk Health Monitor with an authenticating proxy?

Is there anyway to use the BHM, specifically the "Repository Update" option, when you're behind an authenticating proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create a file "ChkBHMRep.exe.config” in the BHM setup folder and update like this  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
     <proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
   </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

It is indeed ChkBHMRep.exe which checks for BHM repositories updates

Let me know if it works

JP Auconie

BHM team